# Sitecore update center - package cannot be loaded

Tags: update-packages

I am getting an error when I click on the updates tab. the error that I get is

```
The packages cannot be loaded. View details
```

When I click view details links, I see the below error message :

```
An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type PackageManagementController. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor.
```

[image]

Can someone please help?

Comment: What is your Sitecore version and is there any error in log?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following in the ConnectionStrings.config

```
<add name="PackageManagementServiceUrl" connectionString="https://updatecenter.cloud.sitecore.net/"/>
```

You can find more information here:
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/platform-administration-and-architecture/en/the-update-center.html

Answer (score 0):

If you have version 9.0.2 - 9.1.1, maybe, you need to update Sitecore Update Installation Wizard.
You can find the package on https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Experience_Platform/91/Sitecore_Experience_Platform_91_Update1.aspx

For 9.0.2:
Sitecore Update Installation Wizard for 8.x-9.0

For 9.1 and 9.1.1:
Sitecore Update Installation Wizard for 9.1